# Foreign objects in javascript-generated SVG

Tags: javascript, forms, svg

I am trying to create an array of simple text inputs inside an SVG that is created dynamically using javascript.

First I was doing it in PHP and there the snippet would look like this:

```
for ($row=0; $row<7; $row++)
{
for ($col=0; $col<7; $col++)
{
    $fx=130+100*$col;
    $fy=120+100*$row;
    echo "<foreignObject x="".$fx."" y="".$fy."" width="50" height="80">\n<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n<form><input type="text" width="1"/ style="font-size:48px; border:none;"></form>\n</body>\n</foreignObject>";
}
}
```

Then in javascript I would try it for a single instance like this but I did not get this to work.

```
var field = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
field.setAttribute("x", "130");
field.setAttribute("y", "120");
field.setAttribute("width", "50");
field.setAttribute("height", "80");
mySvg.appendChild(field.cloneNode(true));
var s = '<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><form><input type="text" width="1" style="font-size:48px; border:none;"></form></body>';
var s1 = document.createElement(s);
field.appendChild(s1);
</script>
```

Any hints? Or should I switch to a completely different implementation (e.g. CSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.createElement requires an element name as an argument and creates a single element, it doesn't parse arbitrary html/xml content.

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) to parse a string of markup.

As for the PHP you probably need to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) the internal double quotes in the echo.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at the DOMParser. (The PHP code works for me, even with the non-escaped quotes.)